# Hiding STL container implementations from users of a class

Tags: c++, containers

I've read that hiding the actual container type used in a class is a good thing. It makes accidentally (or intentionally) writing code that conforms to the actual container type (that may change and break prior code) harder and thus the code is more robust.

Therefore, that means that this is not a good idea; If the implementation changes from a `std::vector` to a `std::list` things will break:

```
class MyType {
public:
    const std::vector<MyType*>& GetChildren() const;
    std::vector<MyType*>& GetChildren();

    const std::vector<MyType*>::size_type GetChildCount() const;
    std::vector<MyType*>::size_type GetChildCount();
private:
    MyType* _parent;
    std::vector<MyType*> _children;
};
```

Using a `typedef` makes it *look* like it's hidden, but a user only need to look at the mouse-over definition (at least in Visual Studio) to see the actual type and code accordingly. Even worse, the compiler doesn't see the `typedef` at all, it just sees the underlying type.

```
class MyType {
public:
    typedef std::vector<MyType*> ChildContainer;
    typedef ChildContainer::size_type ChildContainerSize;

    const ChildContainer& GetChildren() const;
    ChildContainer& GetChildren();

    const ChildContainerSize GetChildCount() const;
    ChildContainerSize GetChildCount();
private:
    MyType* _parent;
    ChildContainer _children;
};
```

**Question:** Is there a way to hide the underlying container type so that it will be difficult for the user to code around it short of wrapping the STL container in a potentially poorly written and not-needed wrapper?

Comment: do you mean, how to hide an underlying container? How about iterators then?

Comment: Instead of providing the getter methods `GetChildren()` provide your own operations to add/update/delete and iterate through the _child_ items.

Comment: See [this related article on *type erasure*](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html).

Comment: Juanchopanza, that is a great article and it hits the question right on the nail. Thank you!

Comment: Read about the [PIMPL idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you have no choice, but to show the underlying container types. For example, for randomly accessed containers like std::vector v, I can do sort(v.begin(), v.begin()+10); whereas for a std::list li, I can only do li.sort(), how can you hide the container type, and only use iterators? These iterators are totally incompatible. Also, container type is one of the most fundamental consideration in software designing, why should you think about the future possibility of changing container type? That usually means bad designing, and total remake of the software.

Comment: +1. I think OP will find that one can't change the public API semantics without breaking someone's code. Like, if they change the type to a set, there will be someone who relied on the order of elements, and if they change to a list, there will be someone who relied on quick random access. It's called [Hyrum's Law](https://www.hyrumslaw.com/).

Answer (score -1):

You should use typedefs and iterators.  Then if you want to change the container, you can because users are only dependent upon the iterators.  People can always break it if they want, but you are exposing an easy way to NOT break.

```
class MyType {
public:
    typedef std::vector<MyType*> ChildContainer;
    typedef ChildContainer::size_type ChildContainerSize;
    typedef std::vector<MyType*> ChildContainerIter;
    typedef std::vector<MyType*> ChildContainerCIter;

    const ChildContainerCIter GetChildrenBegin() const  { return _children.begin(); }
    ChildContainerIter GetChildrenBegin() { return _children.begin(); }
    const ChildContainerCIter GetChildrenEnd() const  { return _children.end(); }

    const ChildContainerSize GetChildCount() const;
private:
    MyType* _parent;
    ChildContainer _children;
};
```

And no there is not a way to really hide it completely.  The compiler needs to know what type it is when their code is compiled.

Comment: Iterators of different containers don't always support the same operations. So this doesn't allow you to change the container without breaking client code. The article I linked in a comment shows some solutions to this problem.

Comment: His question about not writing a poorly written wrapper made me think that he wanted something within that style and not too complicated.  This solution is a big step up from exposing the object because iterator are a LOT more interchangeable than containers.